# Inverses in the spherical interpetration of higher homotopy groups

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, higher-homotopy-groups

I have just started studying the higher homotopy groups $\pi_n(X, x_0)$ in more detail than I have before and I am getting confused about the inverse operation which makes $\pi_n(X, x_0)$ a group. I've been thinking about this for a while and keep getting stuck.

I understand that we can interpret the higher homotopy groups in two different ways. One way is to view them as homotopy classes of functions $(I^n,\partial I^n)\to (X,x_0)$ with the addition operation defined by the class of

$$
(f+g)(t_1, ..., t_n) = \begin{cases}
f(2t_1, t_2,  ..., t_n), \, t_1\in [0, 1/2]\\
g(2t_1 -1, t_2,  ..., t_n), \, \in [1/2, 1] 
\end{cases}
$$
and the inverse operation is defined by the class of
$$
-f(t_1,t_2,  ..., t_n) = f(1-t_1, t_2, ..., t_n)
$$
making the set of homotopy classes a group (here $I = [0,1]$).

The second way to interpret the higher homotopy groups is to view them as homotopy classes of functions $(S^n, *)\to (X,x_0)$. Then in this case the addition of $f$ and $g$ can be viewed as the composition of the maps
$$(S^n, *) \xrightarrow{p} (S^n\vee S^n, *) \xrightarrow{f\vee g} (X, x_0)$$
where $p$ is the map that squeezes the equator to a point and the top and bottom hemispheres become the top and bottom spheres in $S^n\vee S^n$. This is where my confusion comes in.

My question: How the inverse operation defined in the second interpretation of higher homotopy groups? Is there a similar way to write the inverse operation in the second interpretation of higher homotopy groups like there is for the addition?

P.S. You don't need to give me all the details just some hints on where to start on defining the inverse operation is enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably know how the inverse looks for $n=1$: the inverse of a loop $l(t)$ is the same loop but traversed in the opposite direction: $l^{-1}(t) = l(1-t)$. This way, the loop $l l^{-1}$ is homotopic to a constant loop: one can go from $l(0)$ to $l(1)$ and back and this will be $l l^{-1}$, or one can go from $l(0)$ to $l(\tau)$ only and then go back, for some $\tau \in [0,1].$ For $\tau = 1$ gives $l l^{-1}$ and for $\tau = 0$ gives the the loop constantly equal to $l(0)$.

Now, the pinch map interpretation is the same as the composition of loops, except you add some extra dimensions, in which you don't really do anything. Composing two loops is making a circle into the figure "8" and then mapping each of the little circles by each of the loop maps. In higher dimensions, you just perform this operation of every circular section of the sphere. This should give you an idea of how the inverse is supposed to look.

Comment: Yeah, I understand it now. Thank you!